# bbfreeze generated exe does not work

Tags: python, wxpython, packaging

i'am working on freezing a python 2.7 application on windows , the application source code is about 86 Mb with Gui made with WxPython .

the freezing tool I'am trying to use is bbfreeze , the generated result is 166 Mo, but it does not run or produce any results .

here is the bbfreeze script that i worked with :

```
from bbfreeze import Freezer
f = Freezer("Host-1.0.0", includes=("wx", "os", "subprocess", "webbrowser", "decimal", "numpy", "matplotlib", 'socket', "scipy"),excludes=('libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll','libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll'))
f.addScript("E:\source\main.py",gui_only=True)

f()
```

**Remarks** : 
1-while working with bbfreeze , i had the following error :

```
No module named matplotlib.numerix
```

so i have  replaced in the "Python27\Lib\site-packages\bbfreeze-1.1.3-py2.7.egg\bbfreeze\recipes.py" , as indicated in this link https://github.com/schmir/bbfreeze/issues/19

```
    mf.import_hook("matplotlib.numerix.random_array", m)
    backend_name = 'backend_' + matplotlib.get_backend().lower()
    print "recipe_matplotlib: using the %s matplotlib backend" % (backend_name, )
    mf.import_hook('matplotlib.backends.' + backend_name, m)
    return True
```

with

```
 try:
    mf.import_hook("matplotlib.numerix.random_array", m)
    backend_name = 'backend_' + matplotlib.get_backend().lower()
    print "recipe_matplotlib: using the %s matplotlib backend" % (backend_name, )
    mf.import_hook('matplotlib.backends.' + backend_name, m)
    return True
except ImportErrror:
    pass
```

2-someone on my team had already generated a working solution with py2exe , which size is 286 Mo but it runs a little slow , so we are trying to compare working with different tools .

Can any one indicate why doesn't the generated exe work ? and is the size difference between the two generated solutions justifiable ?